# Boost lambda::_1 in C++ 0x

Tags: c++, boost, lambda, placeholder, c++11

```
int main() 
{ 
    std::vector<int> v; 
    v.push_back(1); 
    v.push_back(3); 
    v.push_back(2); 

    std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), std::cout << boost::lambda::_1 << "\n");
}
```

Can this code be translated to C++ without using Boost? I know C++ 0x lambda expression syntax, but didn't try to use placeholders in such context.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No placeholder needed in this case, as lambdas capture the parameter:

```
std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [](int x){std::cout << x << "\n";});
```

Comment: Consider using [] instead of [=], since you aren't capturing anything. That will prevent errors later when you try to capture variables.